# Changes to ApplicationUser property are not written to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have code in my controller to disable an account. The code was working fine. Now, all of a sudden it isn't.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> DisableClient(string userId, int disableAccount)
{
    bool disable = (disableAccount != 0);
    ApplicationUser user = UserManager.FindById(userId);
    if (user != null && user.Disabled != disable)
    {
        user.UserName = disable ? DisabledUserName : user.Email;   // Not sure if this is needed
        user.Disabled = disable;
        // Generating a new security stamp invalidates the user's
        // session, effectively locking them out
        if (user.Disabled)
            await UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(userId);
        await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Details", "Client", new { userId = userId });
}
```

`ApplicationUser.Disabled` was mapping to `AspNetUsers.Disabled`. But now, I can see the code above setting this property to `true`, but the value in the database remains `false`.

I don't understand how this could've changed. Can anyone help explain this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should add context.SaveChanges()

Comment: @swforlife: Neither `ApplicationUserManager` or `ApplicationUser` have a `SaveChanges()` method.

Comment: the context inside should have. see link below

Comment: @swforlife: Could you clarify *context inside*? I haven't found it. The other question appears to have the context, but Identity uses a different one that I use in my own code.

Comment: my bad, can you post your usermanager aswell?
Are you sure your usermanager is using your ApplicationUser

I think this is more like what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22652118/disable-user-in-aspnet-identity-2-0/35310691

Comment: @swforlife: Thanks for your help. Ultimately, it helped me determine what was happening. I've answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I tried adding the following line to ensure the database context was saving the changes.

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationDbContext>().SaveChanges();
```

However, this line caused an exception because my code had produced a duplicate value in an indexed column.

I now assume that my original code was also producing an exception, but it was handled silently. The line above is not needed. As long as there is no hidden exception, my original code works fine. And this explains why it was working but then stopped: Because it had to have two accounts disabled before there was a duplicate that causes the exception.